# How can I avoid repainting a wall after removing pictures?

Tags: walls, repainting

I have off-white walls and when I removed some pictures recently, I filled the holes with spackle but there are still some areas that visibly show where the holes were. I don't want to have to repaint. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to touch up with a color-matched paint?  Might not be a 100% match, but it might look better than just the old spackled hole.

Comment: Hang new pictures that utilize a larger frame. Or you could cover with wall paper.

Comment: This might be more of a "Life Hacks" stack exchange question. I know a lot of the home improvement guys here are more or less perfectionist, and short of rolling the whole wall, you'll be able to see the newly painted areas, since the color, texture and oxidation of the new paint will be visible compared to the existing, even out of the original paint (assuming you had some left over)

Comment: Those annoying stickers on fruit? Stick them on the wall until you can't see the spackle anymore. Or get over your aversion to the correct solution, which is to paint the <expletive> wall already. Wait,  no there is another option - remove all the lightbulbs and cover the windows with tinfoil - you won't be able to see the spackle if the room is in complete darkness.

Comment: Simple - knock down the wall. If there's no wall there, you can't paint it. QED.

Comment: I honestly don't know what sort of a useful answer you expect to get. If you don't want to see something, you have to cover it. What you choose to cover it with is your own choice. Most people would choose paint. I can't believe you have used spackle and then afterwards realised that you can see it!

Comment: You can't really cover holes to match existing paint *without* using paint.

Comment: No one has mentioned wallpaper. Wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

As @jphi1618 said, if the spackle isn't a color match (and it usually isn't), a bit of local touch-up with paint of the right color can solve the problem.

If you don't have leftover paint stored away, hit the paint store for sample chips and use them to find a match. Once you know what color you need, and have figured out whether the surrounding paint is flat or semigloss, see if the store offers 8-ounce samples; those are cheap enough that you can afford to experiment if you aren't sure of your choice.

Try to match the existing texture, and to "feather"/dry-brush the edges of tge new oaint so it blends into what's already there.

It won't be perfect. But it will probably be good enough that nobody but you ever notices it.